# How to pass Activity to the ViewModel?

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have a method, that request permission from user. I placed it in the ViewModel to make it in background, but in order to run it, I have to pass the `Activity` to the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` method. How I may do it?

Comment: "How to pass Activity to the ViewModel?" -- that is not a good idea. If your viewmodel determines that you need to request permission from the user, have your viewmodel emit an event that the activity observes. The activity would then request the permission upon receipt of that event.

Comment: Oh well, I've read some questions here about asking for permissions while using the MVVM, and many answers were about doing it in the view model. Thank you, I'll take a deeper look on that topic once again.

Comment: Checking to see if you need permission can be done in the viewmodel. Actually *requesting* the permission is a UI responsibility.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Putting code in `ViewModel` that somehow requires an `android` context is not a good idea. The purpose of `ViewModel` is too separate itself from all the `android components`. If you will try to force your way by passing `activity's context` in your `viewModel` to somehow make it work, then you will leak context if you are not careful.

A good solution would be to realize which code should relies in `Activity` and which should go in a `viewModel`. If we are talking about granting `permissions`, that sounds like something that should definitely reside in the `Activity` class, as an `Activity` has `API` to deal with requesting for permissions and managing the response from the users, i.e. either permission is denied or not.